# Move .csv files based on their content

Tags: powershell, csv

I'd like to search through a folder of .csv files and select those which contain a date value older than a certain date.
Once I have the files I just want to move them to another folder location.
I have tried this but get the error ***"Move-Item: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or,...."***

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).Date

$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\IMPORT" -Filter *.csv

foreach ($csv in $CsvFiles){
$group = Import-Csv -Path $CsvFiles.FullName | 
Where-Object {$_."Received Date" -as [datetime] -lt $Date} | 
Sort-Object 'Order ID' -Unique | 

forEach-Object {
$_.Group | Move-Item -Path $csv.FullName -Destination D:\EXPORT\$($csv.Name) -Force}}
```

The code is working up to the movement of the files.
I thought that Move-Item would not require a -Path as that should already be present in the pipeline. However not supplying a path results in a Path Null error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The .csv files do not contain their file paths

Comment: This is assuming all CSV files have a column header `"Received Date"` ?

Comment: Did you previously have a `Group-Object` statement somewhere in the pipeline that you've since removed? Or does your CSV file have a `Group` column?

Comment: Yes - All .csvs have a column Header "Received Date"

Comment: No - There is no previously removed Group_Object statement or a .csv column called "Group". But I can see why you would think that $_.Group clearly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I did not understand what you're trying to do, this ***should work***.
Remove the `-WhatIf` switch on `Move-Item` if the script is doing what you expect:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).Date

$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\IMPORT" -Filter *.csv

$toMove = foreach($csv in $CsvFiles)
{
    $shouldMove = Import-Csv -Path $csv.FullName |
    Where-Object {
        $_.'Received Date' -as [datetime] -lt $Date
    } | Select-Object -First 1

    if($shouldMove)
    {
        $csv.FullName
    }
}

Move-Item -Path $toMove -Destination D:\EXPORT\ -Force -WhatIf
```

Comment: Unfortunately all files in the source folder are moved with this solution. Just need to move those in $shouldMove

Comment: @ColinA I'm not following you, `$shouldMove` is just checking if the content of the CSV on each loop iteration has at least 1 date lower than `$Date`, if that's case, the loop will yield the full path of said CSV and store it in `$toMove`, else, no output is produced.

Comment: There are 420 files in the folder. $shouldMove finds 29 of them with a lower date however all 420 files are moved

Comment: @ColinA not sure then, I tested the script myself, with 10 Csvs and it worked perfectly.

Comment: My apologies I had not updated Import-Csv -Path $csv.FullName from my original script. Now working correctly. Thanks very much!

Comment: @ColinA ohhh yeah right, on your script you were using `$CsvFiles.FullName` which is actually an array of **all** the paths instead of ***each element of the array*** (`$csv.FullName`). I missed to point that out, so my bad. And happy it worked out :)